# Can't choose CMYK in Illustrator print colour management

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, cmyk

I'm having an colour issue when printing.
I've been using a Mac for the past 2 years and I never had color problems when printing. (The colours resembled the same as the ones on screen).

Now I had to change to a Windows 64bit machine and the troubles started.
When I want to send a file to my office printer (a Lexmark XS50DE connected to the office network) the settings I get are not as on the MAC and when I print a file the colours are different from the screen (I guess the screen could be calibrated, but the colours i see are not so far from what they should be).

The Graphics Settings are grayed out

[image]

In the color management window I can't select CMYK in the printer profile

[image]

This is the printer's color profile

[image]

I apologize in advance if any infos are missing, just ask and I'll provide any data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that "FollowMe" printer support CMYK??

Comment: I  would say so. If I go to Control Panel/ Color Management / Devices  and select that printer, the ICC profile is set to U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2. The thing is that I can't select that profile in Illustrator

Comment: The OS may allow you to set an RGB printer to use a CMYk profile (incorrectly).... Illustrator *won't* use CMYK settings for an RGB printer though. Illustrator relies on the actual printer driver options, not the OS color profile settings. You need to check the *actual* printer specifications to determine if it supports CMYK. There;s little chance any can help you based on "FollowMe" - no one knows what printer that is or which manufacturer created it.

Comment: The printer is a Lexmark XS950DE. I'm not sure what info I need to provide to get an answer on this

Comment: Sorry. Your question title is quite different than what you are *actually* asking. -- *"I guess the screen could be calibrated"* -- not "could' but "must". fiddling with the out settings isn't going to correct your mismatched color. You need to calibrate *everything* before doing anything else. As for why those options are not available in Illustrator - it's because the printer doesn't support you changing those options. The specs list PCL and Postscript 3 "Emulation" which means it's not directly supported, but translated by the printer driver. Some things may not be translatable.

Comment: The could part was just silly irony. What I don't understand is why the option is not available on Windows while the it is on Mac (which uses the same printer)